# Styling variable in php for email content

Tags: php, html, css

I currently have a form that sends an email with some of the content from the form when a product is created. The trouble I'm having is getting the email content to look right as I can't figure out the styling of the string. Currently I have this setup..

```
$to = "email@email.com";
$subject = $id . " has been added to PMS";
$txt = "<h1>A Product has been added to PMS!</h1> \n<b>Details</b> \nPart Number: " . $id . "\nName: " . $name . "\nProduct Family: " . $family . "\nPRF: " . $PRF;
$headers = "From: email@email.com" . "\r\n" .
"CC: other@email.com";

mail($to,$subject,$txt,$headers);
```

I'd like to add a `<h1>` to the first part but it simply puts out `"<h1>A Product has been added to PMS!</h1>"` I'd also like to add tables etc but can't figure out how to put them in without it adding the tags instead.

Comment: You're sending plain text email. If you want to send HTML email, you have to send HTML email. I **strongly** recommend using a library like SwiftMailer for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to provide content-type in headers.

```
  // To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers[] = 'MIME-Version: 1.0';
$headers[] = 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1';
$headers[] = 'From: email@email.com';
$headers[] = 'Cc: other@email.com';
```

For more information check this link http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php